# Java Test Client can not find properties file in Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, file, testing, properties

I have following set-up in Eclipse:

Project A - A Dynamic Web Project used as a code for Web Service.
Project B - A test client with class containing Main() so that I can test the project A.

Project A contains a properties file which works fine when project A is deployed as web service. But when I run the test from test client project B, the properties file is not recognized. I have created a folder called 'resources' which is at same level as 'src' folder in Project A and this resources folder contains the properties file. The project B has Project A in it's build path.

Project B - Client=> Here is the sample code for the Client project in Eclipe:

```
public class Match {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     MatchService service = new MatchService();
     SearviceRequest request = new ServiceRequest();
     request.setId(1);
     System.out.println("Output -> " + service.process(request)); 
  }
}

Web Project Under Test (Project A):

public class MatchService{
       public ServiceResponse process(SearviceRequest request){
              ServiceResponse resp = new ServiceResponse();
              if (request != null){
                  ServiceProcessor processor = new ServiceProcessor();
                  resp = processor.findMatch(request.getID());

              }
       }
}

public class ServiceProcessor{
       public ServiceResponse findMatch(ID id){
              if (id != null){
                  // Read Properties File. 
                  File file = new File("resources/My.properties") <---This fails when code is called from client. (Gives file no found exception. But File is present.
                  // Connect to database
                  // Get Data
                  // Build Response
                  // Send Response
              }
       }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing some source code, knowing which folder is the root folder and see the folder structure - it'll be really difficult to help you...

Comment: DO NOT post it in the comments - update your question with all the relevant info please.

Comment: Just blind guessing: Did you create the folder 'resources' as a _source_ folder? Otherwise its content won't be on the class path.

Comment: MatchService is part of Project A and it is kept inside root/src. The properties file is kept at root/resources. When I use a local Main() method in Project A, all works fine. If I call this using Main() in a different project B, error occurs. The Project A is added to the build path of Project B in Eclipse.